# Is there a way to automate data import from S3 to Quicksight through manifest file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

My data is stored in a new folder for each day. For example:
/2021/04/01
/2021/04/02
and so on.

I am using a manifest file below to import data:

```
{
    "filelocations": [
        {
            "URIPrefixes": [
                "s3://<folder-name>/2021/04/02/"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "JSON"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make QuickSight to load at least a month worth of data ( pointing something like here s3:///2021/04/) then I can do autorefresh for that month?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of using S3 as your data source, use Athena.  Athena lets you query a set of files in S3 with SQL and this include data across many files and folders.

You can automatically discover the format/fields/schema of your data files and expose them as tables in Athena via AWS Glue Crawlers.

Here are some high level steps but I encourage you to read through the AWS documentation.

1. Create a [Glue data crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) against the parent S3 folder

   - You may also need to create a Glue database as part of this, a Glue database is just pretty much a namespace where the crawler will put the definition of any tables it finds in
2. Run the crawler and it will create tables in your Glue/Athena database
3. Verify the tables created have the expected fields
4. Go to QuickSight and add a new Athena datasource using the Athena/Glue database and the Athena/Glue tables created by the crawler above.